# Wrong duration in MediaRecorder stream on iOS

Tags: ios, mp4, webcam, mediarecorder, getusermedia

I am trying to use multiple files with ffmpeg and I am having a problem with the duration of the files created through iOS devices.

I am recording the videos through the webcam of the device with:

```
mediaRecorder.current = new MediaRecorder(videoPlayer.current.srcObject);
mediaRecorder.current.start();
mediaRecorder.current.ondataavailable = (e) => {
  setVideoCreatedData(e.data);
};
```

Then I am downloading the file to my computer and testing the metadata through https://www.metadata2go.com/ and this is the output:
[image: Metadata]

As you can see, the duration is 0s.

I want to then use this file with ffmpeg, however, it does not detect the duration and therefore I am experiencing problems.

How should I record the video in order to get a proper duration on the file's metadata?

Comment: You're working with so-called *fragmented* mp4 data. It is generated in real time, so its duration (which goes at the beginning of the data stream) is unknown, hence zero. ffmpeg definitely can handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem I am faced with is that I am joining multiple videos through ffmpeg and the video created through iOS devices is handled but it then appears as a still frame on the output video created by ffmpeg. The other videos recorded through Mac or Windows is working great.

Comment: In addition, when I do an ffprobe on the file I get a 0.633333 duration.

```bit_rate:2244291
duration:0.633333
filename:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/example.webm'
format_long_name:'QuickTime / MOV'
format_name:'mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2'
nb_programs:0
nb_streams:2
probe_score:100
size:177673
start_time:0```